# Android Spinner on SurfaceView not dropping down

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to build a camera-app with a spinner in the camera-preview.
I left out some of the camera-code that I thought was unneccassery. The spinner is reacting(changing color) when I press it but does not drop down. My spinner is pretty small(50dp), no arrow is showing, and my phone is old but in good condition(Samsung Galaxy Pocket plus S5301, Android version 4.04). Maybe this has something to do with the surface changing?

Java:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Camera camera;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback;
Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

private LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
private final String TAG = "   CameraActivity";

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_camera, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
    if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your phone does not have a camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}

public void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = camera.getParameters();
    param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    camera.setParameters(param);

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    refreshCamera();
}
```

XML

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="package.main.CameraActivity">


<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></SurfaceView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            //More spinners

     </LinearLayout>

           //Image in the middle of the screen

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

XML values/strings.xml

```
 <resources>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the root layout FrameLayout to RelativeLayout.

As per the documentation FrameLayout should have only one child.

```
    "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. 
    Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, 
    because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's 
    scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. 
    You can, however,
    add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout 
    by assigning gravity to each child,
    using the android:layout_gravity attribute."
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I changed to RelativeLayout. I tried to put FrameLayout around LinearLayout and then around the spinner. Then I removed FrameLayout from the code. But nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are having spinners in horizontal manner.

Spinners will show items by vertically.

[Current Spinners horizontally Aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iadKG.png)

Change LinearLayout's height from "wrap_content" to "match_parent" to view the spinner's items vertically.

[After making changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PeeT.png)